# Назначение QTableWidget выпадающему списку QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox, qstackedwidget

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно на каждый элемент выпадающего списка назначить `QTableWidget`, чтобы при выборе элемента из выпадающего списка появлялась таблица с характеристиками выбранного элемента (которую я заполню позже).

Например, в `Combobox I` выбираю марку автомобиля, появляется таблица, которую я заполняю.

Буду благодарен за помощь. 
PS. Я в курсе, что в сгенерированном классе нельзя писать код, публикую просто как рабочий пример.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("1")
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.add1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("4")
        self.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(self.add2)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 250, 119, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("4")
        self.comboBox.addItem("5")
        self.comboBox.addItem("6")
        self.comboBox.addItem("7")
        self.comboBox.addItem("8")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 1720, 1000))
        Row = 35
        self.row = Row
        Col = 7
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(Row)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(Col)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(237)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        
        for column in range(Col):
            for row in range(Row):
                s = self.lineEdit.setText("")
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(s)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
    
                
        for a in range(7):
            for b in range(Row):
                c = self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                i1 =  QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(c)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(a, b, i1)
                
    def add1(self, s):
        for row in range(self.row):
            if self.tableWidget.item(row,0).text() == s:
                self.tableWidget.editItem(self.tableWidget.item(row, 0))
            
                
    def add2(self, c):
        itims = self.tableWidget.findItems(c, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        if itims: 
            self.tableWidget.setCurrentItem(itims[0])

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Как вариант. 
Класс [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html) предоставляет стек виджетов, в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("PlaceholderText 1")
#        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.add1)
        
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("PlaceholderText 4")
#        self.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(self.add2)
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 250, 119, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Сделайте выбор")        
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("4")
        self.comboBox.addItem("5")
        self.comboBox.addItem("6")
        self.comboBox.addItem("7")
        self.comboBox.addItem("8")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 1220, 500))
        Row = 35
        self.row = Row
        Col = 7
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(Row)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(Col)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(237)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        ''' ???
        for column in range(Col):
            for row in range(Row):
                s = self.lineEdit.setText("")
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(s)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
        for a in range(7):
            for b in range(Row):
                c = self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                i1 =  QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(c)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(a, b, i1)
        '''
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.add1)        
        self.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(self.add2)

        self.tableWidget_1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 3)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 4)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 5)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(6, 3)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(7, 3)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(8, 2)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(8, 4)          # +++
        self.tableWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(9, 6)          # +++
        
        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()           # !!! +++
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_1)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_3)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_4)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_5)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_6)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_7)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.tableWidget_8)
        
        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex)  # !!! +++
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)        
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 2, 0) 
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 3, 0)   
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget, 0, 1, 5, 1)  

        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        
    def add1(self, s):
        for row in range(self.row):
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            if item and item.text() == s:
                self.tableWidget.editItem(self.tableWidget.item(row, 0))
                
    def add2(self, c):
        itims = self.tableWidget.findItems(c, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        if itims: 
            self.tableWidget.setCurrentItem(itims[0])
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(910, 505)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дай тебе бог здоворья

Comment: @Gif спасибо.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour